# Como ler um arquivo CSV em Python?

Tags: python

Preciso ler um arquivo CSV bem grande (+ 300 mil linhas).

Qual a melhor forma de ler um arquivo CSV em `python`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A forma mais simples para ler o arquivo:

```
import csv
ficheiro = open('ficheiro_csv.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(ficheiro)
for linha in reader:
    print linha
```

No entanto é boa prática abrir o ficheiro desta forma:

```
import csv
with open('ficheiro_csv.csv', 'rb') as ficheiro:
    reader = csv.reader(ficheiro)
    for linha in reader:
        print linha
```

Para o caso do ficheiro ter um formato alternativo devemos declarar o delimitador e se tem ou não pelicas:

```
import csv
with open('ficheiro', 'rb') as ficheiro:
    reader = csv.reader(ficheiro, delimiter=':', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for linha in reader:
        print linha
```

Uma forma mais desenvolvida, já capaz de lidar com possíveis erros:

```
import csv, sys
nome_ficheiro = 'ficheiro.csv'
with open(nome_ficheiro, 'rb') as ficheiro:
    reader = csv.reader(ficheiro)
    try:
        for linha in reader:
            print linha
    except csv.Error as e:
        sys.exit('ficheiro %s, linha %d: %s' % (nome_ficheiro, reader.line_num, e))
```

O métodos csv.reader() apenas cede uma linha de cada vez. Logo, pode lidar com grandes ficheiros.

Alguns dos exemplos apresentados podem ser vistos ao pormenor [aqui](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples).

Answer (score 5):

Se o seu arquivo csv é muito grande, pode usar o método read_csv da Lib Pandas. A princípio tem performance melhor que o csv padrão do Python.

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

O retorno é um objeto do tipo [DataFrame.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Answer (score 4):

Veja a seguir como:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Importe o módulo csv, abra o arquivo "eggs.csv" para leitura, itere sobre cada linha e imprima, ou faça o que quiser com o arquivo.

Esse método é valido para python 2.7 em diante.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import numpy as np


arquivo = open('pessoas.csv')
nome,idade,email=np.loadtxt('pessoas.csv',
                            delimiter=',',
                            unpack=True,
                            dtype='str')


linhas = csv.reader(arquivo)

for linha in linhas:
    print(linha)
i=1

while i < len(nome):
    print(nome[i])
    i=i+1
```