# Lendo CSV com Python

Tags: python, csv

Como eu posso ir dando uma "varredura" no arquivo CSV e ao encontrar determinada String na linha do CSV, imprimir em outro arquivo a linha completa com seus valores após a string. Ex Ao encontrar a string "Bruno lorencini", no csv, imprimir em um segundo arquivo. "Bruno lorencini", pageview:1, bounces:2

Comment: Possível duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97269/como-ler-um-arquivo-csv-em-python

Answer (score 2):

**Algoritmo:**

- abrir o arquivo de entrada
- criar o arquivo de saída
- para cada linha do arquivo de entrada,

  - se a linha for igual ao texto procurado por você,

    - mostrar mensagem "Encontrei!" para o usuario
    - escrever a linha do arquivo de entrada, no arquivo de saída

**Código:**

```
with open('arquivo_entrada.csv', 'r') as f:
    with open('arquivo_saida.csv', 'w') as g:
        for l in f.readlines():
            if l.strip() == "Bruno lorencini":
                print("Encontrei!")
                g.write(l)
```

Comment: Oi - desde o Python 3.3 é possível abrir os dois arquivos com um único bloco "with" - dessa forma você economiza um nível de identação, o que é bem bacana para o código.

Comment: E se eu quiser imprimir a linha toda é possível ?