# Como "limpar" um arquivo csv com Python?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, csv, replace

Olá! Sou extremamente novo em programação, então peço desculpas se eu não souber explicar o que estou tentando fazer ou se meu código está muito errado. Tenho uma tarefa recorrente no meu trabalho que é abrir uma lista de restaurantes no Ifood, coletar os preços de cada um deles e calcular a média. É simples, mas toma um tempo considerável. Resolvi então criar um programa em Python que coleta os preços pra mim, com isso eu só teria o trabalho selecionar tudo no Excel e mandar calcular a média. Eis o programa:

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print('Olá! Entre com o link do restaurante do iFood agora.')
site = input()

html = urlopen(site)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
precosLista = bs.findAll('div',{'class':'result-actions'})
csvFile = open('Preços.csv', 'wt+')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)

try:
    for precos in precosLista:
        print(precos.get_text())
        csvPreco = []
        csvPreco.append(precos.get_text())
        writer.writerow(csvPreco)

finally:
    csvFile.close()
```

O código funciona, mas os dados retornados têm um formato estranho. Um exemplo:

```
"


                                                        R$ 71,90


                                                        R$ 59,90














"

"


                                                        R$ 45,90


                                                        R$ 32,90














"

"


                                                        R$ 29,90


                                                        R$ 24,90














"

"


                                                        R$ 29,90


                                                        R$ 24,90














"

"


                                                        R$ 29,90


                                                        R$ 24,90














"

"


                                                        R$ 29,90


                                                        R$ 24,90














"
```

Se eu tento abrir isso direto no Excel, sai extremamente zoado e difícil de manipular. O que tenho feito então é abrir o csv gerado no Word e remover todos os espaços, linhas em branco, R$ e aspas. Feito isso, copio os números pro Excel e aí sim mando calcular a média. Minha idéia então foi criar outro programa pra fazer essa limpeza por mim, utilizando a função replace, o problema é que não consigo fazer funcionar. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Adiciona `.strip()` dps do precos.get_text()

Comment: Jordan, primeiramente seu código está bem bagunçado, dê uma pesquisa aqui mesmo o stackoverflow com o titulo `"Como ler um csv python"`, segue um exemplo básico, da meneira correta de fazer isso[como ler um csv python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97269/como-ler-um-arquivo-csv-em-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: no seu caso, e em casos de .xls ou .csv, recomendo o usado o package "pandas".

Comment: Laerte, obrigado, já melhorou em 1000% o resultado gerado! Valeu mesmo! O único problema que tenho agora é que, de vez em quando, quando um mesmo produto tem mais de uma "versão" (sei lá, temaki com cream cheese ou sem), no csv vem junto dos preço um "A partir de". Será que dá pra eliminar ele também?

Comment: Sim, basta você dar um replace, vou elaborar uma resposta ai você faz o teste.

Comment: Show! Estou no aguardo pra testar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função que faz a limpeza no texto antes de salvar o CSV. Na função eu coloquei pra ele substituir ', " e R$, mas você pode adicionar mais regras conforme você precisar.

```
def clean_up_text(value):

    value = value.replace("R$", "")
    value = value.replace("'", "")
    value = value.replace('"', '')
    value = value.strip() # remove espaços em branco e quebras de linha

    return value
```

Ai basta chamar essa função na hora de salvar o valor: `clean_up_text(precos.get_text())`

Comment: Eu adicionei isto ao código, mas acho que está passando em branco, pois o csv está retornando da mesma forma como antes. Coloquei o def antes disso:
    try:
        for precos in precosLista:
            clean_up_text(precos.get_text())
            print(precos.get_text())
            csvPreco = []
            csvPreco.append(precos.get_text().strip())
            writer.writerow(csvPreco)

Comment: Agora entendi onde chamar a função. Deu MUITO certo aqui. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Disponha amigo! :)